# Object Reference Persisting Beyond Variable Declaration

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I'm building up a client-side collection of data to post to a server. Using the onClick event of an Add button, I'm collecting the form data and storing it in an internal array. This is some faux/sample code to try to demonstrate the issue (I can't share the source, unfortunately).

```
var getDataFromForm = (function() {
    var _internal = {}; /* Based on feedback, I think this is the reason for the behavior I'm experiencing */
    return function() {
      var form = {}; 
      /* Get the form data */
       _internal.name = form.name;
       _internal.id = form.id;
       return _internal; 
    };
}());

var internal = { vals: [] };

function onClick() {
   var newData = getDataFromForm();

   doAjaxValidation({
       success: function() {
           internal.vals.push(newData); /* All values in array have been updated to this newData reference on click */
           internal.vals.push( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newData)) ); /* ugly, but the reference is broken and future clicks work as expected */
           internal.vals.push( $.extend({}, newData) ); /* reference to the object is still persisted through jQuery's extend */
       }
   });

}
```

I'm confused as to why the `newData` reference is handed to the new assignment of `newData` each button click. Each click event is a new function call and `newData` (theoretically) should be a new object which is not related to the `newData` from any other button click.

What am I missing?

Edit: this sample is from a much larger block of code, and I tried to reduce it to the simplest possible expression. Obviously, as-is, this is not a functional piece of code.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is in getDataFromForm... Can you share that code?

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* Not sure, but what we're missing is the  code that is apparently returning the object in question for the assignment. FYI, objects themselves are never copied in an assignment. The value that is copied is the reference to the object.

Comment: Why have you abandoned your own question?

Comment: @Prestaul unfortunately, I cannot share that code.

Comment: @amnotiam "The value that is copied is the reference to the object." This explains the behavior that I'm seeing perfectly. I think I knew this but had forgotten it. Would you add this as an answer so I can select it? I'll update my question to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: @Christopher: Sure, I'll post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you're passing an object,and expecting a copy.

In JavaScript, objects themselves are never copied in an assignment. It's a *by value* language, but in the case of Objects, the value that is copied is the reference to the object. So returning `newData` from `getDataFromForm` will result in a copy of the reference to the same object in each `onClick`.

Comment: Fantastic! Do you have a link to documentation on variable declaration/assignment in JavaScript?

Comment: @Christopher: Sorry, but off hand I don't have any documentation that deals with that specifically. You may want to check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide for some general information. They do include features that are specific to Mozilla, but I think they generally document them as such.

Comment: No prob. We've been grappling with by reference/by value related bugs in JavaScript. http://objrefnotset.blogspot.com/2012/02/javascript-object-and-variable-scope.html. I appreciate the clarity of your insight.